# Django: Contribute to third party app django-lazysignup

Tags: django, django-apps

I want to contribute to django-lazysignup a django third party app. I tried so far the following steps

1. I set up a regular django app named custom-user
2. I used virtualenv and install required library on virtualenv
3. I fork and clone the github repository of django-lazysignup
4. I run the `sudo pip install -e /path/to/folder/django-lazysignup`  command

I am trying to run command `python manage.py makemigrations` on custom-user project but it showing `ImportError: No module named 'lazysignup'`.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

As, per the official documentation, try to install the django-lazysignup using pip

```
   pip install django-lazysignup
```

Once that’s done, you need to add lazysignup to your `INSTALLED_APPS`. You will also need to add lazysignup‘s authentication backend to your site’s `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
  'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
'lazysignup.backends.LazySignupBackend',
)
```

Finally, you need to add lazysignup to your URLConf, using something like this:

```
urlpatterns += (
    url(r'^convert/', include('lazysignup.urls')),
)
```

Here, is an official documentation to follow [Official doc](http://django-lazysignup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installation)

Comment: This instruction for using the app but I want to change the codebase